# How to make forward slashes be respected by java keytool in Cygwin environment?

Tags: java, cygwin, keytool

I'm running the Java keytool program with -v $HOME/.keystore, which works fine in Unix (creates $HOME/.keystore), but in Cygin gets confused - says it is storing

/home/myaccount/.keystore

but fails with FileNotFoundException trying to write

\home\myaccount.keystore

How can I force keytool to use forward slashes?

----> Follow up: thanks to @mikerobi below who answered my question.  A little code frag for bash to use this in would be:

```
keystore="$HOME/.keystore"
if [ `uname -o` == 'Cygwin' ]
then
    keystorefile=`cygpath -wp $keystore`
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`cygpath`](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html) utility, which can convert any cygwin path to a windows path.

```
keytool -v `cygpath -w "$HOME/.keystore"`
```